# Set default value for Postgres JSON column in Rails < 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql, pg

So I'm starting to use the Postgres JSON datatype, now that [there's a lot of fun stuff you can do with it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).
In one of my Rails apps which is not yet Rails 4 (where [support for Postgres JSON has been added](https://speakerdeck.com/mattt/postgres-and-rails-4-nosql-in-your-sql-database)) I added a JSON column like this:

```
create_table :foo do |t|
  t.column :bar, :json
end
```

but I can't figure out how to set a default value for the column.
I tried all variations like `{}`, `'{}'`, `'{}'::json`, `'[]'::json` etc. but I either get an error when the migration runs or it simply doesn't work, meaning the migration runs but, when I create a new `Foo`, `bar` is `nil`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default value by hand inside the model? AR generally butchers or ignores defaults that it doesn't understand.

Comment: Yeah, right now I use a `after_initialize` callback but I generally don't like those...

Comment: try `""`, I believe that is what is used for hstore to denote an empty hash

Comment: ```-- add_column(:foo, :bar, :json, {:default=>""})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 
: ALTER TABLE "foo" ADD COLUMN "bar" json DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: Can you try setting default to "null"?

Comment: Well, it's `null` by default... by default. I don't want it to be `null`, I want it to be `{}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although a bit late, this worked for me (requires Postgres >= 9.3):

```
create_table :foo do |t|
  t.column :bar, :json
end

execute "ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar SET DEFAULT '[]'::JSON"
```

**EDIT:** this answer used to advocate for `to_json('[]'::text)` instead of `'[]'::JSON` - thanks to [@Offirmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715282/set-default-value-for-postgres-json-column-in-rails-4/20746242#comment37252159_20746242) for the hint.

The problem with the old method was that it didn't actually define an array or an object as the default value as one would expect, but a *scalar* (string) that looked like one. Why does that matter?

Postgres allows three kinds of values to be inserted into JSON columns:

1. Objects

   `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUE('{}')`
2. Arrays

   `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUE('[]')`
3. Scalars

   `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUE('"string"')`

The problem is that if you mix these three kinds in the same column, you lose the ability to use the JSON operators. If you set a default of '[]' using the previously advocated method and queried for an array element, encountering a single row with a scalar default value would abort the whole query with an error:

```
=# SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar->>1 = 'baz';
ERROR:  cannot extract element from a scalar
```

Comment: I get the following error: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function to_json(text) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @ManuelMeurer I believe you need a recent version of Postgres for that; I am on 9.3.2.

Comment: Yeah it was added in 9.3. Could you mention that in your answer? Then I can accept it.

Comment: One more tiny thing, can you change the `>` to `>=`? Cheers!

Comment: This syntax also works : `SET DEFAULT '{}'::JSON;` I find it cleaner.

Comment: @Offirmo thank you! Your answer is the one that _actually_ works - mine was subtly broken.

Comment: @ManuelMeurer if you are still working with the JSON datatype, you might be interested in the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Code below works for PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and Rails 3.2.17

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  serialize :your_column, JSON
  before_create do
    self.your_column ||= {}
  end
...
end
```

migration code

```
add_column :your_table, :your_column, :json
execute "ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_column SET DEFAULT '{}'"
execute "UPDATE your_table SET your_column = '{}';"
```

application.rb

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically just do something like this

```
create_table :foo do |t|
  t.column :bar, :json, default: []
end
```

State the default with  `default: []` or `default: {}` or any other thing you feel comfortable with.

Update: Note that this is for Rails 4+

Comment: As mentioned in my question 6.5 years ago, the app was still on Rails 3, so this won't (didn't) work. Could you improve your answer by mentioning from which Rails version on your suggestion works?