# ruby on rails jsonb column default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have a model ProjectKeyword where I use jsonb datatype in the column `:segemnted_data`

```
class ProjectKeyword < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :keyword
  has_many :project_keyword_dimensions
  has_many :dimensions, through: :project_keyword_dimensions

  validates :project_id, :keyword_id, presence: true
end
```

Migration

```
class AddSegemtnedDataToProjectKeywords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :project_keywords, :segmented_data, :jsonb, default: '{}'
    add_index  :project_keywords, :segmented_data, using: :gin
  end
end
```

My problem is when I create new `project_keyword` instance the default value of the `segmented_data` is a string not a hash and I cannot update this field or merge with another hash 
For example

```
[12] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword = ProjectKeyword.new(project_id: 1671333, keyword_id: 39155)
=> #<ProjectKeyword:0x007fd997641090 id: nil, project_id: 1671333, keyword_id: 39155, segmented_data: "{}">
[13] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.save!
=> true
[14] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.segmented_data.update({'new_data' => 'some_data'})
NoMethodError: undefined method `update' for "{}":String
from (pry):14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But when I asign `hash` value to the field `segmented_data` before update then `update` method works fine.

For example

```
[15] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.segmented_data = {'new_data' => 'some_data'}
=> {"new_data"=>"some_data"}
[16] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.save!
=> true
[17] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.segmented_data.update({'new_data_2' => 'some_data_2'})
=> {"new_data"=>"some_data", "new_data_2"=>"some_data_2"}
[18] pry(#)> new_pr_keyword.save!
=> true
```

The question is how to make default value of segmented_data to be a Hash class not a String so method update then will work straight away on this field, after object just was created.

Comment: did you try THIS http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746242/3884750 ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it does not work

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This has worked for me on several projects:

```
add_column :project_keywords, :segmented_data, :jsonb, default: {}
```

(not a string, a ruby hash)

I seem to recall this not working on Rails 3, but it should be fine in Rails 4.

Comment: Fine in Rails 4 - And also in Rails 5.

Comment: Fine on Rails 6 :)

Comment: using `default: {}` was mandated in Rails >= 5 .

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#changes-with-json-jsonb-serialization